# Break Apart Dart Statement

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm trying to get the AngularDart tutorial to work. I've changed the name of the class and am calling a real server. The data in not making back to the list. I suspect the problem is in this code:

```
  final artists = _extractData(response)
  .map((value) => new Artist.fromJson(value))
  .toList();
```

I want to break it down to separate statement, but I can't find any reference to .map in an Internet search. It's not a method on the map collection. How could this be broken apart?

The full method is:

```
Future<List<Artist>> getArtists() async {
await HttpRequest.request(_artistsUrl, requestHeaders: headers).then((response) {
final artists = _extractData(response)
  .map((value) => new Artist.fromJson(value))
  .toList();
return artists;
});
}
```

The called methods are:

```
dynamic _extractData(HttpRequest req) {
  Map data = JSON.decode(req.responseText);
  return data;
}
```

and:

```
  factory Artist.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> artist) =>
  new Artist(_toInt(artist['id']),
      artist['first_name'],
      artist['last_name'],
      artist['notes'],
      artist['primary_instrument'],
      artist['other_instruments'],
      artist['birth_year'],
      artist['death_year']
  );
```

The caller of getArtists is:

```
class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  List<Artist> artists;
  final ArtistService _artistService;
  final Router _router;

  DashboardComponent(this._artistService, this._router);

  Future<Null> ngOnInit() async {
    artists = (await _artistService.getArtists());
    print("Dashboard Length: ${artists.length}"); // this crashes
  }
}
```

### Not an answer, but a fix to the problem

I rewrote getArtists:

```
  Future<List<Artist>> getArtists() async {
    HttpRequest response = await HttpRequest.request(url, requestHeaders: headers);
    List data = JSON.decode(response.responseText);
    final artists = data
          .map((value) => new Artist.fromJson(value))
          .toList();
    return artists;
  }
```

I rolled up the extractData method. The real problem was with the "return artists" being in the inner code block. As a result, it didn't get returned to the caller of getArtists. This problem is also covered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37930524/getting-typeerror-this-getbrowserclient-is-not-a-function) making this question somewhat redundant.

Comment: What's the purpose of "breaking apart"?

Comment: To find out where it's failing. I end up with a null list. I'm not getting any errors so I want to test it step by step. It will also allow me to hopefully find some documentation.

Comment: I would start with printing the JSON you get back and make `JSON.decode(req.responseText)` work.

Comment: It may have worked fine all along. I have print statements just prior to "return artists" and they are all showing valid data. When I put the same statements in the caller, I get a no method found. So the data is not getting back to the caller. I added the caller code in above.

Comment: Your question doesn't show where and how you call `getArtists()`. Maybe you're missing an `var x = await getArtists()` (because it returns a `Future`).

Comment: What do you get when you just print `print(artists)`?

Comment: Null. I've fixed the problem. The return is in the wrong replace.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that `_extractData()` should return a `List<Map>` where each item is a serialized `Artist`

A `List` also has a `map()` method.

```
dynamic _extractData(HttpRequest req) {
  List data = JSON.decode(req.responseText);
  return data;
}
```

would make this code work

```
 final artists = _extractData(response)
  .map((value) => new Artist.fromJson(value))
  .toList();
```

but that depends on what `response` actually looks like.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `.then` of returned by `HttpRequest.request` Future, and its callback parameter is called asynchronously. So the Future is completed, but resulting list is not filled yet. `await` is shorthand for `.then`, try to save `await HttpRequest.request` resulting response to variable and move the callback right behind it.

Comment: Your answer might solve the underlying problem, but I solved it a different way. See above.